# Drupal, user limit to use 3 devices

Tags: security, drupal, ip

hello i just want to know if it possible to Limit an IP address to 3 devices or just limit an account to 3 devices in order to prevent account sharing. using drupal. thanks. :D

Comment: are you storing sessions based on devices.

Comment: i would like to limit the user to login in 3 devices because i will create a website that have a betting, and prevent to sharing account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Session Limit module. This module will help you maintain the number of sessions per user.

Project URL: https://www.drupal.org/project/session_limit

Thanks